# How to access Azure Linux vm via RDP

Tags: linux, azure

I need to access Azure Linux( RedHat 7) via RDP so that we can connect this vm in GUI mode. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To get RDP-like functionality with Linux using Microsoft Windows as the client, look at programs like Xming or X-Win32. You might refer to the CentOS Wiki on the subject: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xming

Essentially it is a three step process:

1. Install X system on the remote system (VM)
2. Install an X tool such as Xming or X-Win32 on the local system
3. Enable X11 forwarding on SSH tunnel (PuTTY, Bitvise, WinSCP, etc)

Be sure to include on the remote system useful X applications such as xterm.

Answer (score -1):

First google result:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop

Linux does not have RDP (that's a Windows protocol), but there are alternative solutions like xrdp. However, first you most likely need to install a graphical desktop environment like xfce4.